# Render partial view with jade on select change

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I need to do the following,

I have a `<select>` (a list of team names), when the user selects a team, I get relevant information re: the team and display it.

How do I do this in jade?

I'm trying the following, (but I'm wrong obviously, I don't see a lot of documentation out there).

Briefly, I'm doing a `include test.jade` on my main page, and a `res.render('test', {team: team_obj});`

**jade:**

```
h1 #{team}.name
h2 #{team}.homeGround
h3 #{team}.manager
h4 #{team}.aka
```

**nodejs:**

```
collection.findOne(query, function(err, team_obj){
    res.render('test', {team: team_obj});
});
```

I'm getting the information correctly in `team_obj`.

Get the following error when I run the app,

> team is not defined

Now this is happening because `test.jade` is getting rendered before I feed it the `team_obj`.

**Questions:**

1) Am I doing this right? is `include` the correct way of partially rendering jade views? if yes, how do I make sure it renders only when the user has selected an `option`?

2) Is there a partial views concept in jade I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 0):

1) you should use `#{team.name}`

2) you can't change the team object once the selector is changed. the template was rendered once with the database result. - such functionality should be handled by client side JavaScript and AJAX calls. partials in templates are just a way to share common pieces of templates, and its done in Jade via `include`.

I don't know what you're rendering and including and when.. but id you use a template variable like #{team.name} you have to make sure that the template was rendered with the team object.